# cakephp validation message not showing

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

i am new to cakephp and am trying to build an app in it. I have some textfields, i wish to have validation on them. I following cakephp tutorials in cakephp.org and did the following but i cant see the validation messages near the textfields. Following is my code:

ctp:

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->text('Rideoffer.PickFrom', 
                                                array('class' => 'address-text',
                                                    'value' => $dropFrom));  ?>
```

model:

```
public $validate = array(
         'PickFrom' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Cannot leave this field blank.'
    ),
    //'PickFrom' => 'notEmpty',
    'DropAt' => 'notEmpty',
   // 'born'  => 'date'
);
```

where am i getting wrong? how do i solve it?

Comment: refer http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have used comma in dropat

```
public $validate = array(
         'PickFrom' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Cannot leave this field blank.'
    ),
    //'PickFrom' => 'notEmpty',
    'DropAt' => 'notEmpty'
   // 'born'  => 'date'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 
    Form->text('Rideoffer.PickFrom', 
                                 array('class' => 'address-text',
                                       'value' => $dropFrom,
                                       'error'=>'Cannot leave this field blank.'));  ?>